# Add button to JDesktopPane

Tags: java, swing, mdi, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I have a question from swing, I have two forms, the first form is for MDI and the second form is for login,
I want when a user enters password and username correct, user can login to MDI‘s form. MDI form use of  `jform`  and login form use of `jinternalframe`, I define `JDesktopPane` and add login to this, but I want to use button in `jframe`(MDI form) , when I add button to `JDesktopPane`, it can add but  I cannot set location of my button.
Please help me how can set location of my `jinternalframe` and button?

This is my code:

```
     Login frame = new Login();
    frame.setVisible(true); 
    desktop=new JDesktopPane();
    desktop.add(frame,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setContentPane(desktop);
    frame.setSelected(true);  
    frame.setLocation(500, 200);

    FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
    desktop.setLayout(flo);
    JButton buttonSaveCustumer = new JButton("Create Customer");
    buttonSaveCustumer.setLocation(70, 80);
    this.add(buttonSaveCustumer);
```

Best Regards

Comment: You need to give us more code. None of us know the class in which this code is being called, what the class 'Login' is, or any context to anything that you posted. Please post your complete code formatted in your question, maybe then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

See below method,//Before using the below method don't forget to set the layout property to null

```
public void setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

Moves and resizes this component. The new location of the top-left corner is specified by x and y, and the new size is specified by width and height.
This method changes layout-related information, and therefore, invalidates the component hierarchy.

```
Parameters:
x - the new x-coordinate of this component
y - the new y-coordinate of this component
width - the new width of this component
height - the new height of this component
```

Comment: thank you, it test this code, but i can not success, the type of login form is JinternalFrame.

Comment: You need to set the layout as null before using this method.Just add (JDesktopPane refe*).setLayout(null) and then use the above method.

Comment: thank you, i can correct this with your code and setLayout(null).

Comment: I edited my post.If this is useful pls tick the answer.